# How best to describe poor communication in terms of low-rate of exchanged messages

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, collocation

I had a communication problem with a customer via an instant messenger. 
Please advice on how to say formally that I had to wait long for his responses and we exchanged just a few phrases per day.

I thought the following was a possible solution:

> "the project completion took longer than expected because communication was too slow."

But I checked collocation dictionaries and did not find a phrase "slow communication".

Comment: Describe what problems this low communication rate is causing you, and ultimately will cause him. Describe the fundamental problem, and low communication rate as a symptom of it. If this isn’t actually a customer but a prospective customer and the low rate is just him not being responsive to your sales pitch, then get a new sales pitch or a new prospect. There’s no way to “formal” your way out of someone who doesn’t want to buy.

Comment: The context of the communication was that the customer did not explain unclear requirements.

Comment: Ok, now we’re one step closer. What does unclear requirements cause? Focus on what the impact is to the customer: he doesn’t care whether his requirements are clear, so what does he care about? What outcome would incentivize him to make his requirements clear? What happens *to him* if he doesn’t clarify his requirements? Maybe he’ll never get the product he paid for? Maybe it will be delayed significantly? Maybe it will be unlike what he wanted?

Comment: @DanBron A thought I want to express is "the project completion took longer than expected because communication was too slow". But I checked collocation dictionaries and did not find phrase "slow communication".

Comment: Now I understand. Can you [edit] that information into your question?

Comment: I think that what you have suggested is perfectly understandable.

Comment: The project took longer to complete than expected because our questions were not answered in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sporadic communication.

'Sporadic' means  - the gaps between communication were long, the communication was 'patchy' and inconsistent, irregular and occasional.

Example:

- ' the project completion took longer because communication with the customer was sporadic'

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sporadic